# How do i print the range with only the first and last numbers in a_list and 'to' in between each?

Tags: python-3.6

Complete the print_first_last(a_list) function which is passed a Python list as a parameter. The function prints the first element of the list followed by " to " followed by the last element of the parameter list.

Note: you can assume that the parameter list contains at least two elements.

For example:

```
(Test => Result)
print_first_last([1, 6, 5]) => 1 to 5
print_first_last(["one", "two", "three", "four", "and", "so", "on", "hundred"]) => one to hundred
print_first_last(["front", "middle", "back"]) => front to back
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_function(a_list):
    print(f"{a_list[0]} to {a_list[-1]}")
```

Comment: what about in the context of a function?